# How to use data generated from two different functions in third function

Tags: javascript

I've two data set generated from two different functions separately. They are different data type and cannot be combined (concat, join, whatever). I want to use those data in the third function like demonstrated below. How can I do it.

```
function a() {
    var x = Math.ceil((Math.random()*100)+1)
    c(x);
}
function b() {
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
    c(y);
}
function c(x,y) {
    console.log(x + ' : ' + y);
}

a();
b();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function a() {
        var x = Math.ceil((Math.random()*100)+1)
        return x;
    }
    function b() {
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
        return y;
    }
    function c(x,y) {
        console.log(x + ' : ' + y);
    }

c(a(),b());
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is usually not that helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Work in test, but I have to see it work in real life. My function is quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function a() {
        var x = Math.ceil((Math.random()*100)+1)
        return x;
    }
    function b() {
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
        return y;
    }
    function c(x,y) {
        console.log(x + ' : ' + y);
    }

    c(a(),b());
```

You call function c() with a() and b() as arguments. That would eliminate the need of global vars and simplyfy debugging significantly!

Answer (score -2):

Can you make variants x and y in public?

```
var x;
var y;
function a() {
    x = Math.ceil((Math.random()*100)+1)
    c(x,y);
}
function b() {
    y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
    c(x,y);
}
function c(x,y) {
    console.log(x + ' : ' + y);
}

a();
b();
```